# Understanding slice indexing without exception

Tags: python, list, exception

I do not quite understand why a slice of a list does not throw an exception, when the low index is larger than the length of the list. Instead an empty list is returned.

```
>> [1, 2, 3][1000:]
[]
```

Why is this?

Comment: this is by design.

Comment: I closed as duplicate, the answers provide all the use cases, your question is covered, I feel that there's no need to clutter the site with more answers. thanks to other goldbadge owners for adding more relevant dupes.

Comment: that's the default behaviour https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations